# Best Practices of Uploading XML files in a Web-Application

Tags: xml, database-design, xsd

What's the best approach (industry standard) when another business needs to upload an XML file into your web-application on a regular basis?  The contents of the XML must be stored in a table.  And, the contents of the XML file needs to be inserted into a parent table and related child table with other relationships to other lookup tables.  There is a XSD for the XML file.  The XSD will change on occassion and I thought of placing a copy of the latest XSD in the web-application for download.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the upload automated or user initiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time HTTP POST the XML to the web site, which would then parse, validate, persist, and send back a confirmation or status of some kind.  I think that would be considered "industry standard."  A push would be required, and the client would use a timed task of some kind to do it on that regular basis.